# While loop using turtle graphic defined function

Tags: loops, turtle-graphics

I'm using a while loop with user-defined functions to make drawings in turtle graphics based on a number of different conditions. For some reason, the while loop completely ignores the iterator making it an infinite loop when it shouldn't be. If you take out the functions that make the graphics, the loop works the way it should. Why doesn't the loop work with the functions for the graphics?

Answer (score 0):

I need to see your code to have a better understanding of what's happening. Other than that, have you given your loop an end case that will keep it from looping? for example

```
i=0
while i<10:
    print(i)
    i+=1
```

the i variable is incremented at the end of every loop, the loop stops once it exceeds 10.
My guess is that the functions you have that make your graphics are not connected to your while loops stoping case.ex:

```
continue=True
while continue==True:
    if #user action == desired output:
    #insert graphic function
    continue==False

    else:
        #enter whatever default action you'd like
```